# How to use two dialogs within a single preference selection

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to create a sound preference that works like the sound selection in the alarm and timer application.  In short, the preference starts with a standard list preference, but once the music or ring tone selection is made, another dialog is displayed allowing the audio to be chosen.

Is my only option to create a custom preference handler ?  Can I capture the initial list preference change and then present the handler for the audio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution.  I extended ListPreference with my own class.  When the dialog is closed, I then call a chooser for the audio list.  When the choose completes, the custom, parent PreferenceActivity is called.

Relevant code bits:

```
public class AlertBehaviorPreference extends ListPreference {
...
    public void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult)
    {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        if(positiveResult)
        {
            String s = this.getValue();
            if(s != null && s.equals(SONG_ALARM_ACTION)) // play song
            {
                // Get the parent activity.  
                // This activity will be notified when the audio has been selected
                PreferenceActivity pActivity = (PreferenceActivity)this.getContext();

                // Select a recording
                Intent i = new Intent(pActivity, pActivity.getClass());           
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.setType("audio/*");
                pActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select song"), 1);

                Log.d(TAG, "Started audio activity chooser");
            }

public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
...
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Call back into the preference to save data
        // Where the result can be validated and settings can be
        // be reset if the user cancelled the request.
        ((AlertBehaviorPreference)(findPreference("alertBehaviorPreference"))).onSongActivitySelectionComplete(data);
    }
```